# Can't get apt-get to work, no module name "Click"

Tags: ubuntu, apt

After my last apt-get upgrade I noticed that TensorFlow stopped working. I tried to update all software again and now my apt-get complains about this "click" module.

```
  % sudo apt-get install -f                                                                                                                                           !9045
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  click
Suggested packages:
  click-reviewers-tools ubuntu-app-launch-tools | upstart-app-launch-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/14,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 482732 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../click_0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Job for click-system-hooks.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
click-system-hooks.service couldn't start.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't install any packages because it gets stuck there.

This is Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Looks like you're lacking a particular python library.

Comment: have a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/613512/how-to-get-removed-a-broken-package-in-this-case-click

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing with PIP instead of Apt? If not, do the following:

1. `sudo apt install python-pip`
2. `pip install click` or `sudo pip install click`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04, solved it by following the instructions given in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/616990/68804

It essentially consists in:

- manually removing all `click` folders from `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages` (there can be several; I had to do it both in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`);
- then running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Click on your system:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install click (or sudo pip install click)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).